# Controlling filter from VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I've got a filter in an Excel sheet.
[image: Picture]

One of the columns in the filter contains dates. I would like to be able to control the filter via VBA so I can configure what rows should be shown based on their dates. For example, in the picture above I've listed three rows. I want to only see the rows which have a date set in February - this would leave me with two rows. Is this possible? I think it should be since the filter functionality recognizes Year-Month-Day hierarchies in dates:
[image: filter]

Recording a macro **does not work**. When I apply changes made to a filter the macro recorder stops with the message "Too many line continuations."

Thanks!

Comment: You are only allowed 24 line continuations, any more will result in the error you saw. Is the macro recorder generating any code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can filter for all dates in a month:

Use the **AutoFilter** method.
Use **Operator:= xlFilterValues**
and **Criteria2:=Array(1, "2/13/2013")**

The '1' represents 'Month'. This will filter for all dates in the month of the date that follows.

Other arguments you can use:

- 0:  year
- 1:  month
- 2:  day
- 3:  hour
- 4:  minute
- 5:  second

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Can you confirm that this method won't conflict with the existing filter shown in my picture? Specifically, I'm working on an application that will create a report. This report will contain all historic data in a single sheet. When the consumer receives the report he should only be faced with the latest month, but still have the option of using the included filter to remove the filtering on latest month to reveal all historic data.

Comment: This method is using the existing autofilter. This corresponds with toggling the February checkbox manually.